# How to compute the character of the Steinberg module for the group $\mathrm{SL}_n$ over a field of characteristic $p$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characteristic-p, characters, modular-representation-theory, induced-representations

It is known that the Steinberg representation $V$ of the group $\mathrm{SL}_n$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $p$ (maybe one needs to assume that $k$ is perfect, I am not sure) is the irreducible module with highest weight $(p-1)\rho$, where $\rho$ is half of the sum of the positive roots. My question is: is it true that $V$ is induced from the one-dimensional representation of the Borel subgroup with the same highest weight? Also, how to calculate the character of $V$ (does the calculation of the character follow from the answer to the previous question)?

Comment: Am I understanding the question properly? If the field $k$ is finite, then the Bore subgroup has index prime to $p$, while the dimension of the Steinberg module is a power of $p$, so it seems that the answer to the first  question is certainly "no".

Comment: The answer to this question likely depends on whether you're thinking of $SL_n(k)$ as an algebraic group (scheme) or as a (finite?) discrete group. At the level of algebraic groups, the Steinberg module can be realized as an induced module, although you need to use the algebraic group version of induction rather than the finite group version of induction. I recommend skimming through Chapters 1 and 2 of the book "Modular Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type" by James E. Humphreys.